# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" when building SQL statement from user input

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to compare a date from user input with a date stored in an Access database, using ASP Classic.

The user inputs a date (`SearchedStartDate`), which is submitted through a form, and then my SQL statement should select records where the start date field is more recent than the date the user inputted.

The Access database field is a Date/Time data type, and my SQL statement is like:

```
SELECT SessionID, StartDate 
FROM   SessionTable 
WHERE  StartDate>='"&SearchedStartDate&"' 
ORDER BY StartDate DESC"
```

I've searched around and tried lots of different things, such as using # signs around the date for Access, and `SearchedStartDate = FormatDateTime(SearchedStartDate, vbShortDate)`, but all my attempts result in a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are you using `ADODB.Connection`, `ADODB.Recordset`, *et al.* to work with the database?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've "searched around" you must have seen warnings that Dynamic SQL is widely regarded as a *bad thing*. The correct approach is to use a parameterized query, for example,

```vbs
Const adDBTimeStamp = 135
Const adParamInput = 1

Dim SearchedStartDate
SearchedStartDate = "2018-01-01"  ' test data

Dim cmd
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con  ' currently open ADODB.Connection
cmd.CommandText = _
        "SELECT SessionID, StartDate " & _
        "FROM SessionTable " & _
        "WHERE  StartDate >= ? " & _
        "ORDER BY StartDate DESC"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", _
        adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , CDate(SearchedStartDate))
Dim rst
Set rst = cmd.Execute  ' ADODB.Recordset
Do Until rst.EOF
    ' work with the values in the current row of the Recordset
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: I do plan on changing my SQL statements to use parameters, but I'm trying to just get it working with the simpler method first. Thanks for your example though, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Benzo how can you accept the other answer, the code is wrong and won't work in VBScript or Classic ASP for that matter!

Comment: @Benzo I can guarantee that `SearchedStartDate = Format(YourDateValue, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")` will fail, there is no `Format()` function in VBScript and VBScript strings do not require forward slashes *(`/`)* to be escaped.

Comment: @Benzo plus any advice that favours SQL Injection riddled dynamic strings over parameterised queries using `ADODB.Command` is plain bad advice, regardless of whether it helped you. I’m more concerned about others finding this question and thinking the accepted answer is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Lankymart thank you for your advice, I've undone accepting the answer. Apologies.

Comment: Should use `adDBTimeStamp` *(135)* for Access datetime parameters, see [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

It should read like this:

```
"SELECT SessionID, StartDate 
FROM   SessionTable 
WHERE  StartDate >= #" & SearchedStartDate & "# 
ORDER BY StartDate DESC"
```

where `SearchedStartDate` should be a string of the format `yyyy/mm/dd` to express your date value. If Format is available, you can do:

```
SearchedStartDate = Format(YourDateValue, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the # signs as suggested and it works. Do I need to use the format yyyy/mm/dd? It seems to work without this step, as the data in my database is in the same format as the date enter by users.

Comment: True date values (of data type Date) carries no format. Access SQL (where you need a string expression for the date value) also accepts the "reverse" US format `mm/dd/yyyy` but any other format will not work reliably.

Comment: I see we have an uneducated and anonymous downvoter among us. May I recommend a tutorial like "Beginning with Microsoft Access" or similar.

Comment: So as long as the data isn't entered in any other format, this will work reliably?

Comment: You should validate your input for being a valid date expression before anything else. Only if accepted, convert to a true date value, and pass it on. Finally, for the query, format it as shown as a string - or as mentioned, use a parameterized query.

Comment: I validate the inputs with regular expressions and only pass them on if they're valid. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no `Format()` function in VBScript and what’s with the escape characters? You don't need to escape `/` in VBScript strings, you got the right language?

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry, I hadn't tried the Format part yet, but the SQL statement part worked.